# Shortcut Icon opening site in browser rather then downloading?

Tags: html, shortcut

I have an issue I want to make a download button for an desktop shortcut to my html. Whats happening is that the code I'm using is not downloading the Shortcut Icon but rather opening the shortcuts targeted location in my browser

The code I am using is as follows

```
<a href="Pheonix M-II.LNK" target="middle">
    <img src="Desktop_Icon.png" border="0" alt="Download desktop Shortcut" width="120" height="30"
         onmouseover="this.src='Desktop_Icon_Rollover.png'"
         onmouseout="this.src='Desktop_Icon.png'">
    </img>
</a>
```

how can I overcome this?

EDIT:

err after testing this is not the case with IE but is so with Chrome and Safari (Which doesn't have my concern as much) completely fails?

Comment: You could use a server-side script to add the .lnk to the data as an attachment. This forces the browser to show a download prompt for it.

Comment: Chrome and Safari probably dont recognize the .lnk file for download. There are no specifiic notations to offer a file for download. .lnk is a windows format so it´s no surprise IE can handle it rather than chrome and safari. What wonders me is that you want to download a reference to a file, not the file itself.